# Approximating multidimensional functions with neural networks

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Is it possible to fit or approximate multidimensional functions with neural networks?

Let's say I want to model the function f(x,y)=sin(x)+y from some given measurement data. (f(x,y) is considered as ground truth and is not known). Also if it's possible some code examples written in Tensorflow or Keras would be great.

[image: function plot of f(x,y)=sin(x)+y]

Comment: in fact, even single hidden layer neural networks are [universal function approximators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem). In practice, the choice of the network architecture matters a lot. If you already have an analytic model for your measurement such as `sin(x) + y` you should use it rather than using a generic model such as a neural network.

Comment: thanks for the hints. Unfortunately I don't know the analytical model...

Answer (score 1):

As said by @AndreHolzner, [theoretically you can approximate any continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) with a neural network as well as you want, on any compact subset of `R^n`, even with only one hidden layer.

However, in practice, the neural net can have to be very large for some functions, and sometimes be untrainable (the optimal weights may be hard to find without getting in a local minimum). So here are a few practical suggestions (unfortunately vague, because the details depend too much on your data and are hard to predict without multiple tries):

- Keep the network not too big (it'hard to define though, unfortunately): you'll just overfit. You'll probably need a LOT of training samples.
- A big number of reasonably-sized layers is usually better than a reasonable number of big layers.
- If you have some priors about the function, use them: for instance, if you believe there is some kind of periodicity in `f` (like in your example, but it could be more complicated), you could add the `sin()` function to some of of the outputs of the first layer (not all, that would give you a truly periodic output). If you suspect a polynom of degree `n`, just augment you input `x` with `x²`, ...`x^n` and use a linear regression on that input, etc. It will be much easier than learning the weights.
- The universal approximator theorem is true on any **compact subset** of `R^n`, not on the entire multidimensional space. In particular, you'll never be able to predict the value for an input that's way bigger than any of the training samples for instance (say you trained on numbers from 0 to 100, don't test on 200, it will fail).

For an example of regression you can look [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.py) for instance. To regress a more complicated function you'd need to put more complicated functions to get `pred` from `x`, for instance like this:

```
  n_layers = 3
  x = tf.placeholder(shape=[-1, n_dimensions], dtype=tf.float32)
  last_layer = x

  # Add n_layers dense hidden layers
  for i in range(n_layers):
      last_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=last_layer, units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Get the output prediction
  pred = tf.layers.dense(inputs=last_layer, units=1, activation=None)

  # Get the cost, training op, etc, just like in the linear regression example
```